# Swapping values of fields in a Structure array

Tags: arrays, matlab, field, structure

I have a structure array:

```
s(1)=struct('field1', value, 'field2', value, 'field3', value)
s(2)=struct('field1', value, 'field2', value, 'field3', value)
```

and so on

How do I swap all the values of field1 with all the values of field2?

I've tried this code

```
a=[s.field1];
[s.field1]=s.field2;
[s.field2]=a;
```

And while I can get the field2 values into field1, I can't get the field1 values into the field2.

Comment: Always tag you questions with a language.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp sorry, forgot! Thanks for the reminder

Comment: Please do not deface your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty much there with your approach. The simplest fix would be to store `a` as a cell array, rather than a numeric array, in order to take advantage of MATLAB's list expansion:

```
s(1)=struct('field1', 11, 'field2', 12, 'field3', 13);
s(2)=struct('field1', 21, 'field2', 22, 'field3', 23);

a = {s.field1};
[s.field1] = s.field2;
[s.field2] = a{:};
```

Where `[s.field1; s.field2]` goes from:

```
ans =

    11    21
    12    22
```

To:

```
ans =

    12    22
    11    21
```

---

For a more general approach, you could utilize [`struct2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html) and [`cell2struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html) to swap the fields:

```
function s = testcode
s(1)=struct('field1', 11, 'field2', 12, 'field3', 13);
s(2)=struct('field1', 21, 'field2', 22, 'field3', 23);

s = swapfields(s, 'field1', 'field2');
end

function output = swapfields(s, a, b)
d = struct2cell(s);
n = fieldnames(s);

% Use logical indexing to rename the 'a' field to 'b' and vice-versa
maska = strcmp(n, a);
maskb = strcmp(n, b);
n(maska) = {b};
n(maskb) = {a};

% Rebuild our data structure with the new fieldnames
% orderfields sorts the fields in dictionary order, optional step
output = orderfields(cell2struct(d, n));
end
```

Which provides the same result.